# Storing values from json object in database - knockout.js

Tags: javascript, php, json, knockout.js

I am currently learning knockout.js and its unique features. I have successfully created a contact form. I am able to add or remove as many contacts as needed. I am not quite understanding the concept of storing the values on the database. I am placing values in a JSON object and then using `$.post("/some/url.php"` to send the values for storage in mysql db. However, is not working at all. I am using php for the server side. How can I store the contact values in mysql db? Also would I need to decode the json object to a normal array in php for storage? [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dLbY7/16/)

```
var initialData = [{
    firstName: "Jenny",
    lastName: "LaRusso",
    phone: "(555) 121-2121",
    alt_phone: "(555) 123-4567",
    main1: false,
    main2: true    
}, {
    firstName: "Sensei",
    lastName: "Miyagi",
    phone: "(555) 444-2222",
    alt_phone: "(555) 999-1212",
    main1: true,
    main2: false
}];

var ContactsModel = function (contacts) {
    var self = this;
    self.contacts = ko.observableArray([]);

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(contacts, function (contact) {
        self.contacts.push({
            firstName: contact.firstName,
            lastName: contact.lastName,
            phone: contact.phone,
            alt_phone: contact.alt_phone,
            main1: ko.observable(contact.main1),
            main2: ko.observable(contact.main2)
        });
    });

    self.addContact = function () {
        self.contacts.push({
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
            phone: "",
            alt_phone: "",
            main1: false,
            main2: false
        });
    };

    self.removeContact = function (contact) {
        self.contacts.remove(contact);
    };

    self.addPhone = function (contact) {
        contact.phones.push({
            number: ""
        });
    };

    self.removePhone = function (phone) {
        $.each(self.contacts(), function () {
            this.phones.remove(phone)
        })
    };

    self.save = function () {
            self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.contacts), null, 2));
        };


    self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("");

    //This is not working
    $.post("/some/url.php", initialData, function(returnedData) {
        // This callback is executed if the post was successful   
    })
};

ko.applyBindings(new ContactsModel(initialData));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle doesn't work because it didn't reference jQuery. Maybe that is your issue. Here's a fiddle with that fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/azurelogic/dLbY7/17/. Now I just get a 404 because "/some/url.php" isn't real.

Edit:

The logic is off as well. You should declare lastSavedJson before the save function. Also, the post needs to be called inside the save. Like this:

```
self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("");

self.save = function () {
    self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.contacts), null, 2));
    $.post("/some/url.php", self.lastSavedJson(), function(returnedData) {
        // This callback is executed if the post was successful   
    })
};

//initial post if it is still needed
$.post("/some/url.php", initialData, function(returnedData) {
    // This callback is executed if the post was successful   
})
```

If you don't actually need to use lastSavedJson for anything else, you could inline that into the post.

I find that it helps if I declare all of my observables first, then computeds, and finally functions.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. But is the logic correct for the post. For example I would like to post if the `save` button is clicked

Comment: Edited answer to address logic issues.